# How to unit test Retrofit server response?

Tags: android, junit, retrofit

I want to view(print to so) the response from the server in JUnit for the following Retrofit api:

```
@GET("search/photos")
suspend fun searchPhotos(
    @Query("query") query: String,
    @Query("page") page: Int,
    @Query("per_page") perPage: Int,
    @Query("client_id") clientId: String = BuildConfig.UNSPLASH_ACCESS_KEY
): UnsplashSearchResponse
```